# leave process group in terminate function

Tags: erlang

this is my question:

I have a group of gen_servers which are started without name and that during the init function use `pg2:join(group, self()).`  Until here it works fine.

I used in terminate function `pg2:leave(group, self()).` but if I kill one of the pids retrieved using `pg2:get_members(group).` the pid of the killed process in still in the list given by `pg2:get_members(group).`

I tried to use the leave function by mean of a gen_server call and in this case it works fine.

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it should work like you describe.  i can stop, crash, or exit(Pid,kill) a gen_server and it will properly leave the pg2 group.  can you show some code?

Comment: @stritzinger sorry about that. didn't know that feature when startedy with this site. just fixed. thanks

Comment: @butter71 i will post it asap. i have to say that in that process i use trapexit...but then: shouldn't a dead process be removed from the group without calling leave function???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a problem on erlang version.